# Leaflet.js: find the shortest distance between two points (user location and array of points)

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to work out the shortest distance between the user location and from some collection of coordinates received from an API, and then I used Leaflet Routing Machine to workout the routes. I'm not sure if I am doing it correctly because when I changed the user location, I still get the same route.

Could you look at my code and advise if I am doing the right thing?

I have the code in Jfiddle.

MY APPROACH:

1. When I have received the latlng for user location and from an array of coordinate from an API. I use the Great-circle distance formula [Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danharper/Nve8Q/)
   to find the distances between all the points and push them in an array called allDistances

2)After that I look for the shortest distance in the array by using this formula

```
function closestDistance() {
 return allDistances.reduce((acc, loc) =>
  acc.distance < loc.distance ? acc : loc
 );
}
```

This is my CODE in  http://jsfiddle.net/jt100/r740b3d2/47/.  I have hardcoded the user location because all the points are located in the US and my current location is in UK so I can't identify routes between countries.

I am still very new to programming. I have been reading about SOLID principle. I want to follow this rule but I’m not sure what I need to change in my code.

Comment: Sounds like a textbook use case of a [nearest neighbour search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search). See https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-knn .

Comment: thanks, i am also looking at this library - https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.GeometryUtil, which one do you think is better ? My data type is not geoJson data will it still work with the library?